# Sumif string is in range

Tags: excel

I am doing a simple sumif. My criteria is a string of 5 characters (e.g., `12345`). The range where I am looking for that criteria contains entries of 10 characters (e.g., `1234567890`), some of which contain the 5-character string I am looking for. How can I tell excel to sum based on cells that contain that 5-character string within the 10 characters in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use wildcards:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"*12345*",B1:B4)
```

Comment: You should probably point out that that will only work if the entries in `A1:A4` are non-numeric. The OP gives 1234567890 as an example, though your formula will fail unless that entry is stored as text.